# AWS Glue Crawler Classifies json file as UNKNOWN

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm working on an ETL job that will ingest JSON files into a RDS staging table. The crawler I've configured classifies JSON files without issue as long as they are under 1MB in size. If I minify a file (instead of pretty print) it will classify the file without issue if the result is under 1MB.

I'm having trouble coming up with a workaround. I tried converting the JSON to BSON or GZIPing the JSON file but it is still classified as UNKNOWN.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck for a couple of hours and removing indents fixed it.

Comment: I have the same probleme. Can you give me more details about these indents? where and how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have two json files which are 42mb and 16mb, partitioned on S3 as path:

- s3://bucket/stg/year/month/_0.json
- s3://bucket/stg/year/month/_1.json

I had the same problem as you, crawler classification as UNKNOWN.

I were able to solved it:

- You must create custom classifier with jsonPath as "$[*]" then create new crawler with the classifier.
- Run your new crawler with the data on S3 and proper schema will be created.
- DO NOT update your current crawler with the classifier as it won't apply the change, I don't know why, maybe because of classifier versioning AWS mentioned in their documents. Create new crawler make them work

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I am able to reproduce the issue where files < 1mb are classified and those > 1mb are left as `UNKNOWN`. The JSON path you supplied is for working with files containing arrays of JSON which isn't relevant in my case as each of our files contains a single object.

Comment: If you change a classifier definition, any data that was previously crawled using the classifier is not reclassified. New data is classified with the updated classifier which might result in an updated schema. [Learn more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html#classifier-defining)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json

When you run a crawler using the built-in JSON classifier, the entire file is used to define the schema. Because you don’t specify a JSON path, the crawler treats the data as one object, that is, just an array.

That is something which Dung also pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that file encoding can lead to JSON being classified as UNKNOWN. Please try and re-encode the file as UTF-8.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to make glue read files with other encoding? Re-encoding seems too much