# How to query a json in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, json, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a json array structure similar to the following:

```
[elem1
 elem2 
 attr
  -- code1
  -- code2
]
```

I was able to upload these jsons and preserved their format correctly, and used AWS Glue to crawl the json and I got all of the proper data structure elements (attr has a lot of sub elements that were correctly extracted).

When I go to Athena; however, and I do a `select *`, I get the 3 base columns (elem1, elem2, attr), but the rows have each of the jsons as a whole:

```
elem1                                            |elem2                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{elem1:"a",elem2:"b",attr:{code1:"1",code2:"2"}} |{elem1:"a",elem2:"b",attr:{code1:"1",code2:"2"}}
```

(with attr as a column name at the end)

Interestingly enough, when I relationalized the data and made it into a parquet file, all of the  fields were preserved, but I am worried of some kind of data loss, since there are multiple jsons stored in one row, so there may be some kind of overwriting issue.

Any ideas on how to proceed? I've been trying to find ways to query the json on Athena, but it may just be a problem with the json itself (I downloaded the json and looked at the structure and it looks fine visually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the JSON format that you are using was not working is because of [this](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#json-data-files). The behaviour is expected and for your JSON file to work properly each record has to be present on separate line. Also refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html) talks about the requirement *To parse JSON-encoded data in Athena, make sure that each JSON document is on its own line, separated by a new line.*

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to reformat the json file completely as I had done in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054281/aws-glue-crawler-cannot-parse-large-files-classification-unknown). Athena does support doing json queries of course, and I suggest using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) for more complex queries.